# SDL 2 how to check for "no modifiers" (keyboard input)

Tags: sdl-2

This is my attempt:

```
const bool MOD_NONE{SDL_GetModState() == KMOD_NONE};

if(MOD_NONE) std::cout << "none" << std::endl;
```

However this does not work. Why?

If I print the integer value returned by `SDL_GetModState()`, without pressing any modifiers the value is 4096. Also why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the SDL (2.0.5) source code, here is the `SDL_Keymod` structure:

```
typedef enum
{
    KMOD_NONE = 0x0000,
    KMOD_LSHIFT = 0x0001,
    KMOD_RSHIFT = 0x0002,
    KMOD_LCTRL = 0x0040,
    KMOD_RCTRL = 0x0080,
    KMOD_LALT = 0x0100,
    KMOD_RALT = 0x0200,
    KMOD_LGUI = 0x0400,
    KMOD_RGUI = 0x0800,
    KMOD_NUM = 0x1000,
    KMOD_CAPS = 0x2000,
    KMOD_MODE = 0x4000,
    KMOD_RESERVED = 0x8000
} SDL_Keymod;
```

The value 4096 you get when calling `SDL_GetModState` corresponds to the "Num Lock" key (which doesn't have to be physically pressed to be active, just like the Caps Lock key).

What you likely want is to check for the Alt, Shift, Ctrl and Gui keys (the Gui key is the special OS-specific key, if I'm not mistaken).

```
const SDL_Keymod modkeys = KMOD_CTRL | KMOD_SHIFT | KMOD_ALT | KMOD_GUI;
const bool MOD_NONE{(SDL_GetModState() & modkeys) == KMOD_NONE};
// or simply
const auto modkeys = KMOD_CTRL | KMOD_SHIFT | KMOD_ALT | KMOD_GUI;
const bool MOD_NONE = !(SDL_GetModState() & modkeys);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for the modifiers definition but couldn't find it.

Comment: It's at the end of SDL_keycode.h, in case you're curious.